# "Add to favorites" option in a soundboard app

Tags: android

I have this code for my soundboard,

public class soundboardActivity extends Activity {

```
View lastClickedView;

    public static void setIntArrayPref(Context context, String key, ArrayList<Integer>       values) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    JSONArray a = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        a.put(values.get(i));
    }
    if (!values.isEmpty()) {

        editor.putString(key, a.toString());
    } else {
        editor.putString(key, null);
    }
    editor.commit();
}



   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
       return true;
   }
   // Contextual Menu
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,  ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

            menu.setHeaderTitle("OPTIONS");
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_contex_apm, menu);

                lastClickedView = v;
    }
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.ctxtapm_opcio1:
                    //favorites

                    switch (lastClickedView.getId()){
                                 case R.id.a1: favorites.add(R.raw.sound1);
                                return true;
                                    }
                                 case R.id.a2: favorites.add(R.raw.sound2);
                                return true;
                                    }
                                 case R.id.a3: favorites.add(R.raw.sound3);
                                return true;
                                    }
                  setIntArrayPref(this, "favoritos", favorites);


                    return true;
                case R.id.ctxtapm_opcio2:
                   //share

                    return true;

                default:
                    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.apm);

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    map.put(R.id.a1, R.raw.sound1);
    map.put(R.id.a2, R.raw.sound2);
    map.put(R.id.a3, R.raw.sound3);



    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {


        final MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,entry.getValue());
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(entry.getKey());

        registerForContextMenu(button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
                sound.start();
            }

        });

    }
```

FavoritesActivity code:

```
   public class FavoritosActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Integer> favorites=new ArrayList<Integer>();

public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttonsample, null);

    return item;  
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> getIntArrayPref(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String json = prefs.getString(key, null);
    ArrayList<Integer> favoritos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (json != null) {
        try {
            JSONArray a = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
                int musicaid = a.optInt(i);
                favoritos.add(musicaid);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return favoritos;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.proba);

    favorites = getIntArrayPref(this, "favoritos");

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, favorites);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 


}
```

}

question is, how can I implement an "add to favorites" option ( favorites are in another activity)  for the contextual menu?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over ride onCreateOptionsMenu with in that create one more ArrayList for favorites .

Store the song id in arraylist for each time.
Store this array list in SharedPreferences object
When user select favourites play navigate to next activity get SharedPreferences.
According to position from the list of favourites play the song.

I hope the above solution is clear for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer! my question now is, how can I create a new button in the favorites activity table row, every time the user clicks in the " add to favorites" option?
Thanks again.

Comment: i didnt get actual flow how "add to favorites" and main screen links.If you have any screen please refer it here

Comment: In the main screen I have two buttons, the one that gets you into the soundboard activity, and the other one that gets you in your "favorites" activity. Every time user clicks "add to favorites" at the soundboard activity, a new button in "favorites" must be created.

I don't know if that's what you ask.

Comment: Instead of Using TableLayout if you use ListView to hold favorites then you can use one single xml file to inflate listitem view(for one favorite) with in that layout you can use one button which will be used for n number of favorites.But be careful you have to write onclick event for that button within getView function of adapter

Comment: Hi again! I'm still trying to get the arrayList on the favorites activity. I've edited the code in the main question with a test i've done to see it works, only with one button and one audio file, but is not working. LogCat in favorites Activity says IndexOutofBoundException: Invalid index 0, size is 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing im not understanding why you took JSONArray to hold the arraylist 2.you are already having favourites arraylist why cant you store that array list in Sharedpreferences if that is not possible you can send array list through bundle object.Its all about just storing the name of song in arraylist to identify in next activity still if you have doubt paste the full code i will edit that

Comment: I've edited with the code I have at the moment, but only for 3 buttons. I can't find a way to make it work.